# How to make an HTML table (in a fixed-width div) adapt to the width of its cells instead of its container?

Tags: html, width, html-table

I'd like to make to following table adapt its width to the cells, instead of its container:

```
<div style='width: 700px; border: 1px solid red;'>
    <table border="1" style='table-layout: fixed;'><tbody>
        <tr>
            <th style="" colspan="3">Group 1</th>
            <th style="" colspan="5">Group 2</th>
            <th style="" colspan="4">Group 3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 62px;">A</th>
            <th style="width: 200px;">B</th>
            <th style="width: 62px;">C</th>
            <th style="width: 62px;">D</th>
            <th style="width: 62px;">E</th>
            <th style="width: 62px;">F</th>
            <th style="width: 62px;">G</th>
            <th style="width: 62px;">H</th>
            <th style="width: 62px;">I</th>
            <th style="width: 100px;">J</th>
            <th style="width: 62px;">K</th>
            <th style="width: 68px;">L</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
</div>
```

The width of the container is narrower than the sum of the cell width. It is okay to show horizontal scroll bar here, but the table just can't be wider than its container. If I calculate the sum width for the colspan and the table, it can do the job, but what if the cells has non-px width, like "%" or "em"? Then static px calculation can't work.

Current effect is:
[image]
The expected effect would be the table's width exceeding the container div's width.

But setting width directly to the table also has problems: the width set for cells will be ignored. For example:

```
    <div style='width: 700px; border: 1px solid red;'>
    <table border="1" style='table-layout: fixed; width: 900px;'><tbody>
        <tr>
            <th style="" colspan="3">Group 1</th>
            <th style="" colspan="5">Group 2</th>
            <th style="" colspan="4">Group 3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 62px;">A</th>
            <th style="width: 200px;">B</th>
            <th style="width: 62px;">C</th>
            <th style="width: 62px;">D</th>
            <th style="width: 62px;">E</th>
            <th style="width: 62px;">F</th>
            <th style="width: 62px;">G</th>
            <th style="width: 62px;">H</th>
            <th style="width: 62px;">I</th>
            <th style="width: 100px;">J</th>
            <th style="width: 62px;">K</th>
            <th style="width: 68px;">L</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
</div>
```

The effect is:
[image]
Note the 2nd cell (should be 200px) is as narrow as the 1st and 3rd one.

Anybody could shed some light on this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add css:

```
th{
    min-width:50px; /*for instance*/
}
div{
    overflow-x:scroll;
}
```

and remove `style='table-layout: fixed; width: 1px;'` from the table

Comment: by the way, I'm not sure if the A B C is content, if so, don't use TH for table content. TH means table header, and is good for the group names, but the rest should then be TD. Just in case

Comment: It is the header part of a bigger table "widget", all of these are header cells.

Comment: please ignore the width:1px; that's some testing code. I pasted here by mistake.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The min-width approach works in most browsers but fails in IE7. Maybe I need to talk to my boss to refuse supporting IE7...

Comment: Yea don't be bothered with IE7, the few that use IE7 are probably not even in your target audience

Answer (score 0):

Would positioning the table absolutely be acceptible?

```
<table border="1" style="position:absolute;">
```

This works such that the div no longer contains the table horizontally.  But, of course, the div also no longer contains the table vertically.  You could work around this by giving the div height manually, though.

Comment: Manually setting height is also hard in my case because the table content changes all the time. But even setting to absolute it seems still can't work because the container has to be "position: relative;"

Answer (score 0):

Merijn's answer works, tweaked slightly, for the fixed-width cells case:

Instead of specifying a global th min-width, specify it per cell like so:

```
<th style="min-width: 62px; width: 62px;">A</th>
<th style="min-width: 200px; width: 200px;">B</th>
<th style="min-width: 62px; width: 62px;">C</th>
```

At least this way, your individual width's are not ignored, giving you a table wider than the container, and with irregular width cells.

Comment: yes, if there's no better choice for IE7, I'll take this approach.